# What is the default Ranger admin username and password for hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:3.0.1

Tags: ambari, hdp, apache-ranger

I use hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:3.0.1 and hortonworks/sandbox-proxy:1.0. as a docker containers. Tried to connect to ranger using admin/admin however without any success - The username or password you entered is incorrect.

Tried to change ranger password in the Ambari [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/112864/ranger-admin-ui-password-change.html) - Ranger Admin user's password for Ambari and Ranger Admin user's password in the Advanced ranger-env part and was not able to login to the Ranger using new passwords. Now I also have Ranger Admin password check alert - User:admin credentials on Ambari UI are not in sync with Ranger

Please clarify the default username and password for Ranger or provide me with steps how can I change it.

P.S. have ranger access as a maria_dev user and can not logging to MySQL DB as a root to try to reset current Ranger password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default password is hortonworks1.